Is the $\partial\bar\partial$ lemma valid for closed $(1,1)$-currents in a standard $\partial\bar\partial$ manifold?
By the standard  $\partial\bar\partial$ manifold, we mean a compact complex manifold which satisfying the following: Let $\alpha \in \Omega^{p, q}(X)$ be a smooth complex differential form of bidegree ( $\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{q}$ ) (with $p, q \geq 1$ ) whose class $[\alpha] \in H_{d R}^{p+q}(X, \mathbb{C})$ is zero in de Rham cohomology, then there exists a smooth form $\beta \in \Omega^{p-1, q-1}(X)$ of bidegree ( $p-1, q-1$ ) such that
$$
\alpha=i \partial \bar{\partial} \beta
$$
where $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ are the Dolbeault operators of the complex manifold $X$.
Of course,  a compact Kahler manifold is a  standard  $\partial\bar\partial$ manifold.  Additionally,  on a Kahler manifold, the smooth form $\alpha$ in the aforementioned definition can be replaced by a closed  $(1,1)$-currents, as shown in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145991/ddbar-lemma-for-positive-closed-1-1-currents

Question: Is the following result correct? Let $Y$ be a standard
$\partial \bar{\partial}$ manifold (not necessarily Kahler) and let
$\beta$ be a $d$ closed  $(1,1)$-current. If there exists a current
$T$ such that $\beta=d T$, does it follow that there exists a
function (in the distribution sense) $f$ such that $\beta=\partial  \bar{\partial} f$ ?

Any clues, comments, or references will be appreciated.
